# In Ruby, how can I sort an array of hashes

Tags: arrays, json, ruby, sorting, hash

I am new to Ruby, could someone help?

I have some product data Json that I need to sort by the expiry date, however everything thing I have tried with .sort_by so far is erroring.

The Json is in this format

```
{"wh_Repeating":[
    {
      "wh": {
        "Item_Number": "111166",
        "Expiry_Date": "2023-05-05"
      }
    },
    {
      "wh": {
        "Item_Number": "111167",
        "Expiry_Date": "2023-05-01"
      }
    },
    {
      "wh": {
        "Item_Number": "111168",
        "Expiry_Date": "2023-05-09"
      }
      }]}
```

in Ruby that shows as

```
{:wh_Repeating=>[
{:wh=>{:Item_Number=>"111166", :Expiry_Date=>"2023-05-05"}}, 
{:wh=>{:Item_Number=>"111167", :Expiry_Date=>"2023-05-01"}}, 
{:wh=>{:Item_Number=>"111168", :Expiry_Date=>"2023-05-09"}}
]}
```

tried alsorts
latest attempt was

```
sorted = jsonIn["wh_Repeating"]
sorted.sort_by { |k,v| v[:"Expiry_Date"] }
puts sorted
```

which gave me
undefined method `sort_by' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
(Exception)

Comment: Since the keys in  Ruby Hashes are sorted by insertion order, I would first extract the keys (using the method `keys`), then sort the keys according to your criterium, and finally create a new Hash in the sorted order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
data = {:wh_Repeating=>
         [{:wh=>{:Item_Number=>"111166", :Expiry_Date=>"2023-05-05"}},
          {:wh=>{:Item_Number=>"111167", :Expiry_Date=>"2023-05-01"}},
          {:wh=>{:Item_Number=>"111168", :Expiry_Date=>"2023-05-09"}}]}

data[:wh_Repeating].sort_by! { |hash| hash[:wh][:Expiry_Date] }

data
#=>   {:wh_Repeating=>               
        [{:wh=>{:Item_Number=>"111167", :Expiry_Date=>"2023-05-01"}},
         {:wh=>{:Item_Number=>"111166", :Expiry_Date=>"2023-05-05"}},
         {:wh=>{:Item_Number=>"111168", :Expiry_Date=>"2023-05-09"}}]}
```

Comment: Note that you must perform this operation on a deep copy if the OP does not want the original hash mutated. The OP should have made clear whether  mutating the original was OK.

Answer (score 2):

Your hash keys are symbols not strings.

`jsonIn["wh_Repeating"]` should be `jsonIn[:wh_Repeating]`

Also, `sorted.sort_by { |k,v| v[:"Expiry_Date"] }` does not mutate `sorted`.

`sort_by` does not mutate the receiver. In other words, the value of `sorted` remains the same. There is a bang version (`sort_by!`) that does mutate (a side-effect) but the use of mutating functions is discouraged.

This does what you want to do.

```
jsonIn[:wh_Repeating].sort_by { |h| h.dig(:wh, :Expiry_Date) }
```

Comment: This returns the array `jsonIn[:wh_Repeating]`, not a hash, and the original hash is left unchanged.

Comment: Not sure I follow. The above returns an array of hashes in sorted order: `[{:wh=>{:Item_Number=>"111167", :Expiry_Date=>"2023-05-01"}…`. Yes, the original hash is unchanged though `sort_by!` is available.

Comment: I, like @spickermann, whose answer was selected, returned a hash, so I assume that's what the OP wanted.

Comment: I suggest you reconsider the use of [Hash#dig](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-dig). Many people would consider `h.dig(:wh, :Expiry_Date)` just shorthand for `h.dig[:wh][:Expiry_Date]`. That would be the cases if the data is known to be correct. If, however, the data were suspect, the difference between the two is important. Suppose `h` had no key `:wh` or it did but `h.dig[:wh]` had no key `:Expiry_Date`...

Comment: ...Then `h.dig[:wh][:Expiry_Date]` would return `nil`, telling you that one of the nested hashes is missing the required key. By contrast, either `h.dig[:wh][:Expiry_Date]` would raise an exception (`undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`) telling you that `h.dig` has no key `:wh` (`h.dig[:wh][:Expiry_Date] => nil[:Expiry_Date]`) or `h.dig[:wh][:Expiry_Date] #=> nil`, telling you that `h.dig[:wh]` has no key `:Expiry_Date`. That pinpoints the error. Now suppose there were many nested hashes. If `dig` returns `nil` you'll have to pour over the data. By contrast, `[]` pinpoints the missing key.

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed the original hash (`h` below) is not to be mutated (modified).

```
h = { :wh_Repeating=>[
        {:wh=>{:Item_Number=>"111166", :Expiry_Date=>"2023-05-05"}},
        {:wh=>{:Item_Number=>"111167", :Expiry_Date=>"2023-05-01"}},
        {:wh=>{:Item_Number=>"111168", :Expiry_Date=>"2023-05-09"}}
      ]
    }
```

As this hash has a single key (`:wh_Repeating`), we can simply write the structure of the desired hash as

```
{ :wh_Repeating=>... }
```

and then compute the value of `:wh_Repeating`.

```
{ :wh_Repeating=>h[:wh_Repeating].sort_by { |g| g[:wh][:Expiry_Date] } }
  #=> { :wh_Repeating=>[
  #       {:wh=>{:Item_Number=>"111167", :Expiry_Date=>"2023-05-01"}},
  #       {:wh=>{:Item_Number=>"111166", :Expiry_Date=>"2023-05-05"}},
  #       {:wh=>{:Item_Number=>"111168", :Expiry_Date=>"2023-05-09"}}
  #     ]
  #   }
```

The original hash `h` is unchanged, which can be easily verified.